# Адаптация изображения под мобильные устройства! html

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, мобильная-разработка, оптимизация-сайтов

Суть заключается в том, что почему-то при открытии сайта через телефон, то он у меня растягивает большое изображение и получается что на сайте кусочек большого изображения.
Хочу сделать что бы была специальная картинка для мобильного устройства, но что-то у меня с этим не растет!

```html
          <div class="w-slider-mask">
          <div class="hero-slide w-slide"><img src="file\imagehome\image home 1.1.jpg" sizes="100vw" srcset="file\imagehome\image home 1.1.jpg 1080w, file\imagehome\image home 1.1.jpg 1600w, file\imagehome\image home 1.1.jpg 1920w" alt="" class="hero-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуй сделать так:
(где я написал 600px можешь другое значение поставить, это влияет на то при какой ширине картинка будет менятся на другую.)

```css
.img_pc{
    display:block;
}
.img_mobile{
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .img_pc{
        display:none;
    }
    .img_mobile{
        display:block;
    }
}
```